# Let $V=\{i\in \mathbb{Z}: 0\leq i< 2^n\}$. Define vector addition and scalar multiplication on $V$ to turn it into a vector space over $GF(2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

> Let $V=\{i\in \mathbb{Z}: 0\leq i< 2^n\}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Define vector addition and scalar multiplication on $V$ in such a way as to turn it into a vector space over the field $GF(2)$.

We know that $GF(2)=\{0,1\}$. I have defined scalar multiplication as $ax=0$ when $a=0$ for all $x\in V$ and $ax=x$ when $a=1$ for all $x\in V$ which works well. I'm stuck on how to define vector addition. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What about binary counting? You can define the addition as if you are adding two numbers modulo $2^n$ using binary representation.

Note that $V$ has $2^n$ elements, and $GF(2)$ has $2$ elements. Therefore, the vector space that you are creating will have dimension $n$. Thus, you will end up with $\{0,1\}^n$. Suppose we have two vectors, $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$. Then $u_i, v_i \in \{0,1\}$, for $1 \leq i \leq n$. So, you can send $\mathbf{u}$ to $u_{\text{num}} = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i\cdot2^i$ and similarly $\mathbf{v}$ to $v_{\text{num}} = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i\cdot2^i$ to get numbers $0 \leq u_{\text{num}}, v_{\text{num}} \leq 2^n-1$. Then you add $u_{\text{num}}$ and $v_{\text{num}}$ modulo $2^n$. The result you can again transform back to binary representation. That last binary representation is then the result of adding $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, because it is again a vector in $\{0,1\}^n$.